# plot 3D and combine in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

i have this matrix `"experiment=2*rand(npoints,3)-1"`.
I want to plot in in 3D,so i use `"mesh(experiment)"`.
How can i take red points in my plot?

Also,i want to implement in the above plot , a sphere with radius 1 at 0,0,0.
I did :

```
mesh(experiment)
hold on
[x,y,z]=sphere;
r=1;
mesh(r*x,r*y,r*z)
hold off
```

but 
1) i am not taking radius 1
2) the figures just showing in the same graph but don't combine

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scatter3` to plot points

```
scatter3(experiment(:,1), experiment(:,2), experiment(:,3), '.r');
```

See-thru mesh

```
mesh(r*x,r*y,r*z,  'FaceColor','none', 'EdgeColor','b')
```

Or semi-transparent mesh

```
mesh(r*x,r*y,r*z,  'FaceColor','w', 'EdgeColor','b')
alpha(0.5)
```